# How to check if new user registration in wordpress is already in a third party system

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, action, registration

I have a Wordpress/WooCommerce site that communicates with our back end system via API. I am able to use a SOAP API to query our back end database but am not sure how to integrate it into the user registration form for new user/customer. Specifically, I would like to be able to call the API to verify that a new user's email address is either already in our back end database or is a new user in both places. I need to be able to make this API query when the user/customer enters a  registration email and let them continue to register new if they are not, but send them to the login/password (forgot password) if they are already in the backend database.

I am not sure what hook (if any) is available when the user enters their email address and then how to call my custom code with that email address at that time.

I did find the woocommerce_register_form hook, and added an action there, but this appears to fire when the form is displayed. I need to figure out how to know that the username (which I will require be their email) has been entered and then have my code run, and either continue or pass to the Login form.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post/ before the user is created, or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/ after.